# Managing transaction across function

Tags: java, transactions

We have a java application where before this all was done in the run function of the multithreaded application. Now we are moving out some codes to a separate function. We have to make some variables as global including the connection so that it can be used in the function. Below is the skeleton of the run and calling of the function. The issue now those queries which are process in the if statement and they run into problem then the whole thing goes into catch and rollback. The problem here now is that those which are called in the processOne function and if they run into any catch the general queries which are run after if else is executed too. Is there any way to stop or linked it to the processOne error? Our idea is to use a global variable because tried the dbConn.rollback in it also it do work.

```
public void run() {
 try{
  if(){
    //process here
  }
  else{
    // call function processOne
  }
  //some other general queries
  dbconn.commit();
 }

 catch (SQLException ex){ 

  try{    
  dbconn.rollback();  
  } 
  catch (Exception rollback){    

  }
 }
}

void processOne(){
  try{
   //process queries here
  catch (SQLException ex){                         
    try{    
     dbconn.rollback();  
    } 
    catch (Exception rollback){    

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is throw an exception from `processOne` function, and then catch it in the 'run` function and rollback the transaction:

```
public void run() {
 try{
  if(){
    //process here
  }
  else{
    // call function processOne
  }
  //some other general queries
  dbconn.commit();
 }

 catch (SQLException ex){ 

  try{    
  dbconn.rollback();  
  } 
  catch (Exception rollback){    

  }
 }

  catch (Exception ex){ 

  try{    
  dbconn.rollback();  
  } 
  catch (Exception rollback){    

  }
 }
}

void processOne() throws Exception{

   //process queries here

  }
}
```

That way the entire process is rolled back.

Comment: great it works perfectly well but we need to remove the try and catch in the processOne function right. Another thing I would like to confirm is it ok to declare the dbConn outside the run function else it cant be share across the functions right?

Comment: 1. You don't have to remove the try..catch (if you like to log the error) but in the catch block you need to re-throw the exception. 2. there is no problem defining it as global outside of the function.

Comment: @I tried without removing it at first then it does not work. I guess missing this re-throw exception how to do that?

Comment: just add in the catch phrase: `throw ex`

Comment: I have put this catch (SQLException e){ ystem.out.println("\nSQL Error here :");e.printStackTrace(System.out);throw e;} . Well it just printed twice in the processOne function and the run function. In addition I would also like in multithreaded environment I also have moved some variable to global type is there any memory problem could arise?

Comment: regarding the first section, i did not understand if that's a problem ot a good thing (that it printed twice), as for the second part, you should probably have the DB connection as a singleton so only one instance of it is created.

Comment: Yes I do not see any problem in printing twice so that is solved. Regarding singleton how normally is that worked out? Do you mean to call a function to create the connection but then how is it going to be shared? Currently we are using pooling too.

Comment: I google it but if I do not use it is that ok can I leave as per now?

Comment: might cause performance issues, as each thread would be creating a new jdbc connection, which is expensive.

Comment: But I am using connection pooling so will that be fine?